# Highcharts: Update several series at once, for smoother animation

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts spline chart with three series:

```
series: [
  {
    name: "item1",
    data: []
  },
  {
    name: "item2",
    data: []
  },
  {
    name: "item3",
    data: []
  }
];
```

I periodically get fresh data, then update each series in turn, using the [`Series.setData`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData) function, like this:

```
function update(data) {
  const s = myChart.series;
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    s[i].setData(data[s[i].name]);
  }
}
```

where `data` is an object like this:

```
data = {
  'item1': [1, 2, 3],
  'item2': [1, 2, 3],
  'item3': [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I would prefer to update all the data at once, but this doesn't seem to be possible. When I update all three series in rapid succession like this, the animation is very choppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what seems to be a good solution:

```
function update(data) {
  const s = myChart.series;
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    s[i].setData(data[s[i].name], false);  // add "redraw=false" argument
  }
  myChart.redraw(); // trigger redraw at end of loop
}
```

Adding `false` to the `setData` function prevents Highcharts from redrawing after each change. When I get to the end of the loop, I manually trigger a redraw.

This makes the updating much smoother!

Comment: This not only makes the render smoother, but also uses a lot less resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like this:

```js
const receivedData = {
  'item1': [1, 2, 3],
  'item2': [1, 2, 3],
  'item3': [1, 2, 3]
};

const update = data => Object.keys(data).map(key => ({ name: key, data: data[key] }));

console.log(update(receivedData));
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. It seems I need to call `setData` for Highcharts to register the change.

Comment: I see. I thought you could update the series array at once and I was wrong about that, but it seems you solved it :)